# How to make a textEditingController global

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a global TextEditingController  `final TextEditingController _notes = TextEditingController();` and want to use in other files. is there any way to do that? It is not working globally as I do for other variables. for each file(where I need to use) I have to declare again.

Comment: you can use state management to store this or else you can try declaring globally, can you share sample code of what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final TextEditingController notes = TextEditingController();
```

Declare this outside only one class in which you are using this or declare it outside  main.dart. And call it where ever you want to call in any class.

**Imp Point:**

```
final TextEditingController _notes = TextEditingController();
```

Adding ( _ ) before any variable makes it private in dart.

Comment: I was Adding ( _ ) to my variable. I remove it it is working now.  thanks, Maqsood

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class GlobalVar {
  GlobalVar._();
  static final textEditingController = TextEditingController();
}

Widget someWidget() {
  return TextFormField(
    controller: GlobalVar.textEditingController,
  );
}
```